# Merchant acount in android market

Tags: android, google-play

I want to setup Google merchant account in android market for selling my apps. I am Indian and in the country dropdown India is not available. How can I create my merchant account, and can I use another account like paypal for selling apps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

If your country is not on the list of countries eligible for creating merchant account, you cannot publish paid apps, unfortunately. You will need to find different ways to monetize your application, which might be one of the following:

- As mentioned above, get a PayPal account and ask users for donations
- Sign up to ad-serving site ([AdMob](http://admob.com) seem to be popular choice) and place a banner in your application.
- Implement in-app purchases in your own manner, independent from the Android Market in-app purchases.

Comment: "Implement in-app purchases in your own manner" isn't against Google rules, which my result ban for my account, not only delete my app?

Answer (score 2):

@jubin though its more than a year when you asked this question, but now india is in the list of countries where android developers can create merchant account m happy for it..:-). check it [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/09/21/developers-from-india-can-now-sell-apps-in-the-play-store/)

EDIT: It was the mistake of Google, they put India in list for small time and later they removed again, now India is not in the list..:(

Edit: This time i am happy to edit my answer...:) Good news --> Indian android developers can set up merchant account on google play developer account..:)
check this [here](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=150324)

Answer (score 1):

The way I understood i.
If it is not in the list you cannot join. I happen to be in the same situation. You can sell your apps with Paypal but not on Google's official site. On your own site or on third party sites that accept you.

Comment: +1, "You can sell your apps with Paypal but not on Google's official site. On your own site or on third party sites that accept you." That require to user modify the setting and allow third part, unknown source: source of pain for him,

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice table on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Market) where you can see in which countries selling of apps is possible.
As mentioned before, to "sell" Apps, you could accept PayPal-donations, display Ads oder sell the App on Google-independent Markets.

Answer (score 0):

From India you can not open merchant account yet. And according to the Google TOS, it is in short against rules to earn money on Android Market in a way that that money does not pass through Google (so they get a cut). But it looks like that they tolerate that.